# Need a review of my solution to a probability theory question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, solution-verification

A treasure chest has a .3 chance of having a gold bar, a .5 chance of having nothing, and a .2 chance of having two chests inside, each of which has the same probability as the original chest.
What is the probability that the chest contains at least one gold bar?

Here is my math;

```
Let P be the probability that there is at least 1 gold bar in the chest
P = .3 + .2*(P^2 + 2*P*(1-P))
rearranging we get
.2P^2 + .6P - .3 = 0

Using the quadratic formula we get
P = .436492
```

This matches with some code I wrote;

```
import random

max_depth_hit = 0
def chest_has_gold(curr_depth, max_depth=1000):
    if curr_depth > max_depth:
        print('hit max depth')
        return False
    rand_int = random.randint(1, 100)
    if rand_int <= 80:
        global max_depth_hit
        max_depth_hit = max(max_depth_hit, curr_depth)
        return rand_int <= 30
    
    return chest_has_gold(curr_depth + 1, max_depth=max_depth) or chest_has_gold(curr_depth + 1, max_depth=max_depth)

if __name__=='__main__':
    test_cases = 100000000
    found_gold = 0
    for i in range(test_cases):
        if chest_has_gold(1):
            found_gold += 1

    print(f'probability of finding gold after {test_cases} tests is {found_gold / test_cases}')
    print(max_depth_hit)
```

which outputs
`probability of finding gold after 100000000 tests is 0.43649836`

Can someone take a look and let me know if my work is correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.